# LLVM IR with JAVA-API

Tags: java, llvm

I'm using ANTLR4 as Frontend and want to create my IR with LLVM. I'm using the JAVA-Api for LLVM from JavaCPP.

Because I hate the docu...How can I add a Variable with this Api? Accordingly, I need a solution for local and global variables. If someone has a corresponding documentation or a good example, I would be very grateful.

Many thanks

Comment: new [GlobalVariable](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html)(…) will do for globals. [LLVM uses SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) so local variables are best avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as far as documentation goes, there is close to none for the LLVM C API. The C++ API on the other hand has some documentation for most of its methods which is why the "documentation" or "learning path" to using LLVM is usually just reading through relevant bits of its source code. I'm sure you've seen it before, but I'll link the offical C Doxygen index here as well. https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMC.html

The offical language reference manual is also good at describing certain topics like metadata, attributes and so on. https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html

As user arnt mentioned, for global variables, we use what is in the C++ API, known as GlobalVariable. In the C API we have functions for the LLVMModuleRef type which does what the C++ API does. For the most part, this is just attaching a new name (variable name) to the module with a type and optionally a value.

Using the JavaCPP presets for Java, we can use the following snippet to declare a global variable in our module named "my_global" which is an 8-bit integer with an initializer value of 42.

```java
LLVMContextRef ctx = LLVM.LLVMContextCreate();
LLVMTypeRef i8 = LLVM.LLVMInt8TypeInContext(ctx);
LLVMValueRef value = LLVM.LLVMConstInt(i8, 42L, /* signExtend */ 1);
LLVMModuleRef module = LLVM.LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext("my_module", ctx);
LLVMValueRef global = LLVM.LLVMAddGlobal(module, i8, "my_global");

LLVM.LLVMSetInitializer(global, value);

// Always remember to clean up your resources from the native APIs
LLVM.LLVMDisposeModule(module);
LLVM.LLVMContextDispose(ctx);
```

Local variables are usually not referenced by name (although you can name block-local IR variables), and they are built using SSA form. This means you need to translate whichever structure you use to represent into something which can be turned into SSA form.

Looking at the Instruction Builder APIs (https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreInstructionBuilder.html) we have the functions you're going to be using to create the LLVM IR.

An expression of "2 + 2" should be translated into a LLVMBuildAdd call with the appropriate operands. Again, have a closer look at how to flatten your AST into 3-address code or a similar flattened structure. Once you have this down, you can easily map your own 3-address code into LLVM IR.